# Connect to Remote MSSQL db from Linux Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, sql-server-on-linux

I have a linux docker container built on **microsoft/mssql-server-linux/** image. The container doesn't have anything at this moment, I am trying to connect to remote MSSQL db hosted on windows server somewhere. I am not sure exactly how can I do that.

The documentation for microsoft/mssql-server-linux/ doesn't provide much of details. Any help would be appreciated.

**Updated:**
I have got container working now. But, the container gets exited with code 0 if I try to create and seed db through bash script.

Here is **docker file & docker-compose** files

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
        ACCEPT_EULA: Y
        SA_PASSWORD: Password
        PATH: /opt/mssql-tools/bin:/opt/mssql/bin:$PATH
    container_name: db

FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
EXPOSE 1433
RUN echo $PATH
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
COPY ./db/* /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN ls
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/dbInit.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/dbSeed.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

Here is my **entrypoint.sh**:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & /usr/src/app/dbInit.sh
```

**dbInit.sh** contains SQLscripts to create db, some tables and seed them. something like this.

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P password -d master -Q "CREATE DATABASE dbo"
```

The docker-compose up --build successfully creates db, tables and seeds them. But the container is exited with code 0. Seems like SQL Server it self is closed.

Comment: That image is the **server**, if you have already server elsewhere, you really shouldn't be using that.

Comment: @James Thank you. I think i should change my question. So, i need to access remote sql db from docker container.  Any ideas or thoughts? I have  a postgres db i am able to connect to it from docker container using postgres image. But not with MSSQL.

Comment: Hi James, I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you connecting a mssql engine to another mssql engine? Are you trying to use linked servers? Or are you just trying to connect to mssql running on Docker from *another* docker container that includes an application?

Comment: I am trying to connect remote db on windows server from a docker container. And use this container as a link to api docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear..see the <kbd>[Connect and Query](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)</kbd> for more details

1.First you have to install SQLCMD tools,as they are not installed automatically

- Import the public repository GPG keys.

> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

- Register the Microsoft Ubuntu repository

> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list

- Update the sources list and run the installation command with the unixODBC developer package.

> sudo apt-get update 
>   sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev

You can check out for further enhancements here :<kbd>[Install tools on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu)</kbd>

now you can query like below

**for local :**

> sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ''

**For remote:**

> sqlcmd -S 192.555.5.555 -U SA -P ''

Comment: Thank you for  your response. I tried this, got the following error.                       Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error c
ode 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or
instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Se
rver. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct.....

Comment: Thank you for the help !!!. I have got that working now, but there seems to be an issue with container being closed.  I have updated my question. Thank you once again.

Comment: I am not sure,can you please add an update section and add more details

Comment: There is an option to ouput sqlcmd errorlog to file ,try adding that and also try adding some kind of print after final line ,I am mobile,will try to check more once I am at laptop

Comment: @Aj1:can you try above mentioned steps and update question

Comment: I did, there are no errors actually. It is the sqlcmd that keeps exiting the session.

Comment: It executes all the steps properly with out errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145932/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-aj1).