# Auditing in a SQL Server Docker Container

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, audit

I'm currently using a SQL Server docker container, setup according to the following: [Run the SQL Server 2017 container image on Docker on Linux, Mac, or Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker#upgrade-sql-server-in-containers).

I'm unfamiliar with Auditing within SQL Server, but all the documentation I can find for it appear to be using SSMS to configure the process. I am unable to use SSMS in my particular context.

Is there a way to setup SQL Server Auditing within the SQL Server docker container?

Comment: Why can't you use SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to connect your sqlserver from outside using SSMS..like i mentioned in this answer:[Connect to Remote MSSQL db from Linux Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333252/connect-to-remote-mssql-db-from-linux-docker-container/44333508#44333508)

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification) has SSMS equivalent scripts for auditing..

first you need to try creating server level audit on

```
USE master ;  
GO  
-- Create the server audit.   
CREATE SERVER AUDIT Payrole_Security_Audit  
    TO FILE ( FILEPATH =   
linux file path) ;   
GO  
-- Enable the server audit.   
ALTER SERVER AUDIT Payrole_Security_Audit   
WITH (STATE = ON) ;
```

then you could individual databases as well or server level events as well.Below is one small example for database level audit

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;   
GO  
-- Create the database audit specification.   
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION Audit_Pay_Tables  
FOR SERVER AUDIT Payrole_Security_Audit  
ADD (SELECT , INSERT  
     ON HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory BY dbo )   
WITH (STATE = ON) ;   
GO
```

you can run above scripts through sqlcmd,my answer i mentioned has more details on how to do this

further i think VSCODE is more flexible to run ssms scripts than sqlcmd.you can download it for free and configure mssql extension

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL script to setup [SQL Server audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-audit-transact-sql) and [audit specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-audit-specification-transact-sql) and then execute it with the [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) command usint the -i option.

You can use the [LOGbinder SQL Audit Policy Wizard](https://www.logbinder.com/Form/LBSQLwizard) to help you creating the script.